# Autocomplete not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am struggling with autocompletion via CodeIgniter. I followed a tutorial on http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/ .
I changed my database etc and the variables but when changing the database to one that not exists it doesn't gives any error so I guess it's something in the view itself but can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance

```
        <?php 

        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en-US">
            <head>

                <link href="<?php echo base_url() . 'resources/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css' ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.js' ?>"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js' ?>"></script>

                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        alert('test');
                        $(function() {
                            $("#test").autocomplete({
                                source: "birds/get_birds"
                            });
                        });
                    });

                </script>
                <title>Add Project</title>


            </head>

            <body>
                ID :<input type="text"  id="test"> <br>

            </body> 
        </html>
```

Here is my controller :

```
        <?php

        //birds.php
        class Birds extends CI_Controller{
          function index(){
            $this->load->view('birds_view');
          }

          public function get_birds(){
            $this->load->model('birds_model');
            if (isset($_GET['term'])){
              $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
              $this->birds_model->get_bird($q);
            }
          }
        }


        ?>
```

Here is my Model :

```
        <?php
        //birds_model.php (Array of Strings)
        class Birds_model extends CI_Model{
          function get_bird($q){

            $this->db->select('Code');
            $this->db->like('Code', $q);
            $query = $this->db->get('R_Projects');
            if($query->num_rows > 0){
              foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['Code'])); //build an array
              }
              echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: debug your model and see if the `echo json_encode` print an output?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem when I fill in a false database name (doesn't exist) the page doesn't give any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  source: "birds/get_birds"
```

needs to be this :

```
  source: "<?php echo site_url('birds/getbirds'); ?>"
```